# .giltab-ci.yml inheriting single job from a file in "include"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a template repo that I am linking in "include", and linking a specific file.
Is it possible to only link specific jobs from that file? Or will all jobs in that yaml get executed if link the whole file from the repo that I am linking with the "include"?